# how to speed up my program's startup

Tags: c++, c, linux, ipc

My program needs to load many big wordlist files, so it always takes a long time to start up.
it's so inefficient to recover quickly in crash.  I have a raw idea, but I am not sure if it's feasible. Is it possible to load the files into shared memory and just attach to it when starting up?

Could you give me some ideas or suggestions? Is there any valuable instance?

Comment: You know, you could fix the crashes...

Comment: there are 10 files of over 20GB size, in binary format.

Comment: Does it start frequently? E.g. if you expect it to run for days on end, a few minutes' startup is not much of an issue.

Comment: Loading the files before starting up? Will you hold that for a long time? It costs resources of the computer, maybe that's not a good idea. You might consider multi-thread program, one thread to load your files (before done, set a lock); and the other just start up, if actions use unfinished loading files, just show a warning first and let user wait.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: do you answer that to those who program document auto-save?

Comment: @moala: auto-saves are there for the off-chance that something goes wrong to avoid *losing data*. It's not to speed up application restart in case of crash. If crashes are frequent enough tho make application restarts a performance issue, I say one solution is to get rid of the frequent crashes.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes: sometimes, the app actually "running" is more important than "not crashing". If it takes 1h to start/restart, that may be more annoying.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes, actually there are some programming approaches that suggest exactly the opposite: that crashes are not a big deal as long as you can come back up after a crash very quickly. Erlang does things that way for example, and it's used for high-availability telecom apps. I'm not necessarily saying that this applies to tom_cat's situation, but sometimes solving uptime concerns is more practically done by making sure that failures are graceful rather than eliminating all points of failure.

Comment: @DSM: ... and as long as the crash doesn't destroy anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's definitely possible, provided you design a format which supports
static initialization, or is just raw data.  There are two
possibilities:  if you can design a raw data format (nothing but PODS,
and no pointers); and if portability isn't a concern, including accross
different versions of the compiler (you provide the file as part of your
executable package), then you can normally just `mmap` the file.
Otherwise (what I've usually done), you can write a small program which
will convert your data into C++ definitions (again, only PODs) with
initializers (static), compile it, and link it in, either as a DLL or
statically.

Comment: does it take a long time to compile a 20G executable? :)

Comment: @yi_H I wouldn't be surprised if compilers ICEd.

Comment: @yi_H I don't know, but you only do it once.  And it's only data declarations.  I've used the technique a couple of times.  But it's definitely most advantage when the data must have a special structure: using a pre-compiled version of the structure is definitely a lot faster than reparsing it each time you load the program.

Comment: Object file formats aren't that hard to figure out. If your compiler chokes on 20 GB, have it a few small files (~20 kB will do), and reverse-engineer the format. Then create a small script to create the object files directly, and hope the linker doesn't choke either.

Answer (score 13):

If you're loading 200GB of data, you are either doing something really wrong, or your application doesn't need to startup quickly.

Comment: If you assume your average mechanical hard disk can read data at 100MB/s, then for 200GB you are looking at ~33 minutes to sequentially read all that data. You can't possibly be loading all this into memory at the same time (unless you have 200GB+ RAM) - it sounds like you should be using a database.

Comment: in fact, my program is creating index while loading these files. So there is no need for 200G+ RAM.

Comment: answer his questions, not your question.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the access pattern of your program, you might be better off accessing the wordlist in pieces as you need it, rather than loading the entire thing into memory on every startup.

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is excellent for such purposes. You'll have to go through the process of importing your wordlist into the database file, and then you'll be in business.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split the word list into many dynamic / shared libraries.  For example, one library would contain the common words.  This small one you would load at start up.  The other libraries you would load on demand.  This would reduce the start-up time.

A key principle to reducing start-up time is to only load items that are necessary at start-up.  Other items can be loaded on demand, as necessary.